# HXT: Handling byte order mark from HTTP response body

Tags: haskell, hxt

Using HXT I'm parsing the XML response body of an HTTP call that was made using http-conduit.

```
val <- runX $ readString [withValidate no] (Data.ByteString.UTF8.toString . toStrict $ getResponseBody response) >>> getChildren >>> ...
```

Depending on the version of the API, I found that the response body includes a byte order mark before the XML:

```
error: ""\65279<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><Enume..."" (line 1, column 1):
unexpected "\65279"
expecting xml declaration, comment, processing instruction, "<!DOCTYPE" or "<"
```

Since the BOM may or may not be there, I did the following:

```
...
let resBody = Data.ByteString.UTF8.toString . toStrict $ getResponseBody response
    parseBody body = runX $ readString [withValidate no] body >>> getChildren >>> ...
xs <- parseBody resBody
val <- case xs of
  x : _ -> pure x
  _ -> head <$> (parseBody $ drop 1 resBody)
...
```

It works, but it's printing the error message when the BOM is present. What are the options for parsing the XML with a possible BOM so that it's not printing error messages?

Comment: What is `toString`? What package is it from/what *exactly* does it do? Does it decode? (How can it, without the `encoding` info from the XML? But if it doesn't, how do you get a BOM rather than the bytes that a BOM is made of?) It sure seems like *somebody* in this chain isn't doing Unicode right.

Comment: From https://hackage.haskell.org/package/utf8-string-1.0.2/docs/Data-ByteString-UTF8.html#v:toString "Convert a UTF8 encoded bytestring into a Haskell string. Invalid characters are replaced with '\0xFFFD'."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, given that you're willing to assume the encoding is UTF-8 as you do here, then probably the simplest is to just pattern match to discard a BOM:

```
case toString ... of
    '\65279':s -> s
    s -> s
```

As an aside, having just looked through the XML spec to see how encodings are supposed to be handled, let me just say: eugh, gross. There appears to be no encoding-agnostic way to specify what encoding to use, so the only really correct, robust thing to do is try a bunch during parsing and hope one succeeds.

Comment: So if I wanted to test for the BOM to determine encoding (heaven forbid the response header, BOM, and XML each specify a different encoding), I have to code that bit up myself? Does HXT not already have a means of detection and decoding built in?

Comment: @Sledge I don't know. The [hxt-unicode](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hxt-unicode-9.0.2.4/docs/Data-String-Unicode.html) package does appear to have the necessary functionality, but a source dive would be required to know how and when the higher-level packages call those, as it doesn't seem to be discussed very much in the documentation (that I could see from 15 minutes of browsing). I do encourage you to have a grep for the relevant functions in the hxt source base (e.g. `getDecodingFct`) to learn more.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. In the end, I just went with [xml-conduit](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xml-conduit). It handles BOM-checking without extra coding on the developer's part. It can also process lazy bytestrings.